# How do I read the last line of a file which contain specific pattern with a bare Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl

I need to read a file to the end and get the last line that contains a specific regex pattern. I don't have the [`File:ReadBackwards`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File:ReadBackwards) module.

I tried the code below but found that I do not have [`PerlIO::reverse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::reverse) installed either.

I can't install modules. Kindly suggest code to achieve this.

Ultimately I want the line of the file which begins with the pattern

```
(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) --
```

This is what I tried

```
open my $rev, '<:reverse', '$slogfile';

while ($line = <$rev>) { # do to contents reversely     
    print OUTLOG $line if $line =~ m/^(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) --/;
    close($rev);
}
```

Comment: Could you please share test string!!

Comment: When you use `close` such way a maximum of one iteration of `while`-loop can occur

Comment: @red0ct Got it.  Will use close outside while loop. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What makes you think you can't install CPAN modules?

Comment: Moreover I would say I am not allowed to. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read file as usual, test each line with your pattern and save full line each time it matches. When file is finished, print out what you saved - it will be last match.

```
open my $fh, '<', $slogfile;
my $last_match;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (m/^(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) --/) { $last_match = $_ }
} 
print OUTLOG $last_match;
```

Comment: Would it be not time and resource consuming??

Comment: @STJ It depends on your input data. You can start with the [`Benchmark`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) module to measure how much time it takes for different input, if you want

Comment: Yes, this could be slow for large enough files. In that case it would be better to read chunks from the end and reassemble broken lines.

Comment: @STJ: You must *never* try a more complex approach until you are certain that the simplest way will not work for you. You should already have tried this